# After the program runs once the main section of code loops itself once before proceeding and unsure why?

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I just figured out a way to remember the users last menu selection by utilizing a Python list, but after implementing and running it, after the code has cycled through once, I choose an option from  the menu and it loops itself once then proceeds as normal.

To begin with, I thought it might have to do with the python list needing to bear cleared, but I tried `thislist.clear()` and no luck. Then, I thought it had to do with the `number` input variable needing to be used in the main section of the code, however it did not work. Unfortunately, I have had no further inspiration of what it could be, so your help would be greatly appreciated, please!

Program goes as follows:

```
global thislist
thislist = [""]

def menu():  
    number = int(input("\nEnter option 1 or 2: ")) 
    return number

while True:
    try:  
        option_chosen = menu()
        if option_chosen == 1:
            balance()
    except: 
        break
```

Displays: Enter option 1 or 2: 1

```
def balance(): 
    while True: 
        try:
            selected_option_01 = int(input("\nEnter option 1 for view: "))
            if selected_option_01 == 1:
                view_bal = open("current_balance.txt", "r")
                print("\nBalance: " + view_bal.read())
                view_bal.close()
                thislist.append("balance")
                break
        except ValueError: 
            print("\n######      Not an option. Try again.      ######")
            continue
        finally: 
            add_trans()
        break
```

Displays: Enter option 1 for view: 1

Displays: Balance: 0

```
def add_trans(): 
    while True:
        try: 
            more_trans = int(input("Enter option 1 for menu or 2 for another transaction: "))
            if more_trans == 1:   
                menu()
            elif more_trans == 2:
                if "balance" in thislist:
                    balance()
                elif more_trans == 3: 
                    break                        
        except ValueError:
            print("######      Not an option. Try again.      ######")
            continue 
        break
```

Displays: Enter option 1 for menu or 2 for another transaction: 1

Now it loops back to the start of the code:

```
global thislist
thislist = [""]

def menu():  
        number = int(input("\nEnter option 1 or 2: ")) 
        return number
    
    while True:
        try:  
            option_chosen = menu()
            if option_chosen == 1:
                balance()
        except: 
            break
```

Displays: Enter option 1 or 2: 1

Displays: Enter option 1 or 2: 1  # this section prints twice after returning to start

Displays: Enter option 1 for view: 1

Comment: Tl;dr - voted to close on that basis. Please provide a [mre] - _minimal_ - and a very specific description of the problem - if there’s an error message then edit the __full text__ of the message into your question. _as text_

Comment: I don't get what you mean by the code loop itself once before proceeding? The main part starts from choosing an option, then go to `balance()` or `savings()` based on option chosen, and finally call `add_trans()`, where does it loop itself once? We don't test every case to find what problem you are facing, so can you provide a test run of what input you are using?

Comment: @barny. Are the changes I made more like what you suggested?

Comment: Perhaps you forget to add variable `thislist`, it is currently not reproducible.

Comment: @adamkwn. Ok, just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prompts printed twice are came from different call. The first prompt is made by the `menu()` under `if more_trans == 1:`, it asks for input, return result to nothing and do nothing to future function call. As while loop does not break when no error raised, it starts again and the second prompt came from `option_chosen = menu()`, the input is used in repeated process.

Although you have edited to make the example smaller for us to follow, I want to give some suggestions to your original code.

1. Pass the variable as function parameter so no global variable is needed.
2. Don't put all of your code inside `try`, let it handle the part that will raise error only.
3. You can check with string directly, so most of the try except can be removed.
4. Use `with` to open file, it will help you to close the file after operation automatically.
5. Can use a single file to save account balances.
6. Missing condition:

   1. `new_bal_entry` is written directly if no existing value, while `new_bal_entry` may not be a number.
   2. option being 1, 2 and >3, how about == 3?
   3. `balance()` option 2 does not append `thislist`.
7. `balance()` and `savings()` are almost the same which can be combined.
8. As pointed out above, `menu()` under `if more_trans == 1:` just ask for input but do nothing afterwards, you should integrate your `menu()` in main part.

The code below may not be the best, but should work better.

```
import random
def menu():
    while True:
        print("""
Which account would you like to access?

            1. Balance
            ----------
            2. Savings
            ----------""")
        account = input("\nEnter option: ")
        if account in ("1", "2"):
            access(account)
            break
        else:
            print("\n######      Not an option. Try again.      ######")

def access(account):
    with open("acc.txt", "r") as a:
        bals = a.readlines()
        bal = float(bals[int(account)-1].strip())
    while True:
        print("""
What would you like to do?

1. View
---------
2. Update
---------""")
        action = input("\nEnter option: ")
        if action == "1":
            print(f"\nBalance: {bal}")
            break
        elif action == "2":
            while True:
                try:
                    val = float(input("\nEnter amount: "))
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Amount not correct.")
            with open("acc.txt", "w") as a:
                bals[int(account)-1] = f"{bal + val}\n"
                a.writelines(bals)
            break
        else:
            print("\n######      Not an option. Try again.      ######")
            continue
    add_trans(account)

def add_trans(account):
    while True:
        print("Would you like to do anything else?")
        print("""
            1. Menu
            ----------------------
            2. Another transaction
            ----------------------
            3. Quit
            ----------------------""")
        action = input("\n" + "Enter option: ")
        if action == "1":
            menu()
            break
        elif action == "2":
            access(account)
            break
        elif action == "3":
            print("\nTransaction ID:", random.randint(0,9999))
            break
        else:
            print("\n######      Not an option. Try again.      ######")

menu()
```

acc.txt:

```
0
0
```

Test run:

```
Which account would you like to access?

            1. Balance
            ----------
            2. Savings
            ----------

Enter option: 1

What would you like to do?

1. View
---------
2. Update
---------

Enter option: 1

Balance: 0.0
Would you like to do anything else?

            1. Menu
            ----------------------
            2. Another transaction
            ----------------------
            3. Quit
            ----------------------

Enter option: 1

Which account would you like to access?

            1. Balance
            ----------
            2. Savings
            ----------

Enter option: 2

What would you like to do?

1. View
---------
2. Update
---------

Enter option: 2

Enter amount: 100
Would you like to do anything else?

            1. Menu
            ----------------------
            2. Another transaction
            ----------------------
            3. Quit
            ----------------------

Enter option: 3

Transaction ID: 8170
```

acc.txt after:

```
0
100.0
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding, so the `option_chosen = menu()` line caused the second prompt to occur because it was doubling up `menu()` unnecessarily? That line, however, was there to bring `menu()` into the main code through a variable, which I was doing because I saw it somewhere and understood it as best practice, but you are saying this is incorrect, and it is better to include it in the main code and call `menu()` ? As well, thank you for the feedback, and I will apply your solution and learn from it.

Comment: Another quick question: why am I adding `account` in parentheses with the `access` function?

Comment: @wallace First question, `menu()` and while loop are separated, the code in `menu()` only ask for input and return that input, that's all, nothing related to go into the main code. All the repeated process are done by the while loop, and you already ask for input in each while loop. `menu()` and while loop can be separated, combining them is just a suggestion, let's say you put the while loop part in a function call `main(...)`, then the input part should move out `main()` and you should call it like `main(menu())`.

Comment: Check where you saw the practice you described, I think you are missing something there. Tell me if I'm wrong, I'm happy to learn from that.

Comment: Second question, variables in defining function parentheses called parameters, which describe the arguments function need to receive, while arguments means the actual values received and used by the function. `access(account)` therefore means `access()` need to call with a variable. Noted that, name `account` appeared in both `menu()` and `access()`, but they are different, `account` in `menu()` is a variable saving the result, and pass to `access()` as an argument. while `account` in `access()` is a variable used within `access()`. Their names no need to be the same,

Comment: Ok, anyway, what you suggested seems to be much cleaner than what I had, so your advice is best followed. Regarding the function question, so pretty much the value of `account` is being passed onto the function `access()`? On top of that, is that way better than before because it is more fluid, or is how I had it completely wrong? One last thing, `bal = float(bals[int(account)-1].strip())` this section of code gives me the error `IndexError`?

Comment: @wallace Nothing wrong to do something in your style, when it can be run and is without error. All changes by me are just suggestions that you may have a try, but not mean to be best practices. Lastly, what is the value of `account` when it raises `IndexError`? Noted that my `acc.txt` starts with two lines with one `0` in each. Reading from an empty file will raise error.

Comment: No worries then, thanks! Yep, that's the issue, I didn't pre-set a figure in the `acc.txt` file. With that said, why is it necessary to set two lines with 0, as well why is it necessary to have `bal = float(bals[int(account)-1].strip())`  and how does it work?

Comment: @wallace `bals = a.readlines()` turn lines in file to a list, that is `['0\n', '0\n']`, `[int(account)-1]` will be the index to get the item, `index` == `0` when `account` == `1` and `index` == `1` when `account` == `2`. You can't get something from an empty list so that's why the pre-set `0` is needed. Now we have `0\n`, we remove newline by `strip()` to `0` and then convert it by `float()` to `0.0`. It's the existing value that you can view or update.